# How to alternate between two value every nth row in a column

Tags: excel, vba, row

I want to input "Dark" and "Light" from row 2 onwards where it inputs "Dark" for 2 rows, then "Light" for 2 rows, and so on until the last row of column "A"

Example of what it should look like

```
A  Phase
1  "Dark"
2  "Dark"
3  "Light"
4  "Light"
5  "Dark"
6  "Dark"
... ...
```

I've tried this code below but it is very inconsistent for repeating "Dark" and "Light" every 12 rows and alternating between each value from row 3 onwards

```
Sub light_dark()
Dim dws As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim value As String

Set dws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
lr = dws.Range("A" & dws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

dws.Range("B:B").EntireColumn.Insert
dws.Range("B1").Value2 = "Phase"
dws.Range("B2").Value2 = "Light"


For i = 3 To lr 'row index
    j = (i - 1) Mod 25 '0 to 12 hours count
    If j < 14 Then
        value = "Dark"
    Else
        value = "Light"
    End If
    dws.Cells(i, 2).value = value
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Does "Example of what it should look like" has a meaning, except confusing us? Do you try (in code) placing 12 rows of "Dark" followed by other 12 of "Light"? If not, please explain (**in words**) what exactly you try accomplishing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea of your code (to use `Mod`) is okay, but there are some details off.

If you want to have `n` times the same string, then `n` times the other, you need to use `Mod 2*n` (in your case, n=2 and 2*n=4). Using `Mod 4` will return 0, 1, 2 or 3. The values 0 and 1 (`< n`) stands for the first string (= `dark`), the values 2 and 3 (`>= n`) for the second string.

You should start the calculation with the value 0, so subtract the start row (in your case 3) from `i`.

```
Const n = 2
Const startRow = 3
For i = startRow To lr 'row index
   j = (i - startRow) Mod (n * 2)
   dws.Cells(i, 2).Value = IIf(j < n, "Dark", "Light")
Next i
```

Or use a similar logic as formula into your column B:

```
=IF(MOD(A3-1;4)<2, "Dark", "Light")
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, test the next way. It should be very fast for even very large ranges. It works in memory, loading `arr` array and drop the processed result at once, at the code end:

```
Sub light_dark()
 Dim dws As Worksheet, lr As Long, i As Long, j As Long
 Dim boolDark As Boolean, arr
 Const C1 As String = "Dark", C2 As String = "Light", repNo As Long = 12 'rows to repeat (you can play with it...) 

 Set dws = ActiveSheet ' ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
 lr = dws.Range("A" & dws.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
 
 dws.Range("B:B").EntireColumn.insert
 dws.Range("B1").Value2 = "Phase"
 dws.Range("B2").Value2 = "Light"
 
 ReDim arr(1 To lr - 2, 1 To 1) 'redim the array to keep processed result
 boolDark = True 'initialize the boolean variable to start with Dark
 
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr) Step repNo
        For j = 1 To repNo
            If i + j - 1 > UBound(arr) Then Exit For  'when the array last row has been reached
            arr(i + j - 1, 1) = IIf(boolDark, C1, C2) 'load the aray with the appropriate string constant
        Next j
        boolDark = Not boolDark
 Next i

 'drop arr content, at once:
 dws.Range("B3").Resize(UBound(arr), 1).Value2 = arr
End Sub
```